# Do worlds survive game deletion?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

If you delete Minecraft from your iPad, will you get your worlds back when you download it again?

Answer (score 2):

No. If you delete an app. all data will be deleted with it.

Apps that still have the data after reinstalling them use some kind of sync.

The only way to restore data from an app is to restore from a backup. That will restore everything that is in that backup. You cannot selectively restore just one app's data.